# php : Capturing the command output

Tags: php

I am using exec function to execute the specific executable files in php .

```
exec ( $file , $output , $return_value  ) ;
```

When the given file executed successfully I am able to get the output in the second argument 
by checking the return values , So, It is working fine. But My requirement is when the command execution getting failed due to some reason.  I need to get that error message of that executed program . What I need to do to get the error . through second argument we can get the  successful output only . Not error message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The second argument `$output` only captures `STDOUT` from your executable. Error messages are usually sent to `STDERR` so that they easily can be written to an error log or similar, but this means that you won't see them when you call `exec`.

If this is a linux system, you could append `2>&1` to your command, in order to redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT`. I haven't tried this, but it should forward the error messages to your $output variable.

**Edit:**

I've read up on it on [www.php.net/exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), and it seems this would work.

```php
exec($file.' 2>&1', $outputAndErrors, $return_value);
```

It is also possible to redirect the errors to a temporary file and read them separately.

```php
exec($file.' 2> '.$tmpFile, $outputOnly, $return_value);
```

**Edit 2**

It seems windows also uses this Bourne style output redirecting syntax, so the examples should work for windows too.

[More on input and output streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep stderr and stdout separate, try **proc_open**:
  http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Answer (score 0):

The `$return_value` will have the error code returned by the program which should be meaningfull enough, I don't think you can have better.