# Run exe file from server, render to client

Tags: php, html, webserver, exe

I would like to know if it's possible to run a executable file (through any technology; PHP, JS, HTML...) on the web server, and render the image on the client.

I would like to do that to not share the exe file, but just let the client see what how the programm looks like without having him to download it. Also, using that way it won't affect the client PC.

Comment: why dont u just include screenshots of your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to run application on server side and display result of application to client [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099617/php-capturing-the-command-output)]. However, if your application uses [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) it might be difficult and required complex solution.

What if you:

- Display screenshots of application
- Let user book some online meeting where you would present the application through skype with shared desktop
- Have public server where application would be installed and user could request username/password to server and try it itself (think about security!)

Comment: Well, thanks for the recommendation... A video might be the easiest solution in my case.