# Redirecting the output of a shell command using PHP's exec() function

Tags: php, linux, apache, shell

I am trying to redirect the output of a shell command, like so:

```
# echo here > /tmp/output
```

I need to do this from inside a PHP script being executed by apache using the exec() function:

```
var_dump(exec('echo here > /tmp/output'));  // string (0) "", no file created
```

The above command does not create the file and returns with an exit code of 0.

I can verify PHP is able to execute commands using exec, like this:

```
var_dump(exec('echo here'));  // string(4) "here"
```

I have tried executing this code from inside a php shell running as the apache user, and it works:

```
# su -s /bin/bash -c 'php -a' apache
php > var_dump(exec('echo here > /tmp/output'));  // file is created
```

I have tried redirecting stderr as well as stdout:

```
var_dump(exec('echo here 2>&1 /tmp/output'));  // string(0) "", no file created
```

And finally, I have tried redirecting the stderr from the entire command back to exec():

```
var_dump(exec('echo here > /tmp/output 2>&1')); // string(0) "", no file created
```

Based on the steps above it seems to me that the issue must be related to apache calling php, since it works fine running from a php shell as the apache user.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099617/php-capturing-the-command-output

Comment: areyou trying to keep the output?

Comment: No the output is irrelevant.  The real goal is to use mysqldump to write to a file in /tmp and that is what is failing.  The echo was just a simplified test case.

Comment: tried somewhere else than `/tmp` had issues with linux deleting my files if i was not carefull

Comment: Does the Apache user has the correct permissions to write in `/tmp`?

Comment: Check that php-cli and the module or FCGI you use from Apache share the same `php.ini` file. Also check your setup doesn't used PHP-FPM and a specific pool that would set a user/group different from the main Apache config. You could confirm that by running `$processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid()); print $processUser['name'];`in both instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue.  The problem was apache was configured to use private temp directories:

> PrivateTmp=   Takes a boolean argument. If true, sets up a new file
>   system namespace for the   executed processes and mounts private /tmp
>   and /var/tmp directories inside it,   that are not shared by processes
>   outside of the namespace. This is useful to   secure access to
>   temporary files of the process, but makes sharing between   processes
>   via /tmp or /var/tmp impossible. All temporary data created by service
>   will be removed after service is stopped. Defaults to false.

As a result I was looking in the wrong place for the output of my script.